# html data after login to mail server

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to use http request sampler to retrieve the html data of the inbox page from long time. But not getting success.I am getting only the source code of pages before login but not after login. Can anyone help please.

Comment: Sounds like your login is not active when you're trying to fetch a page that needs you to be logged in. You probably need to pay attention to something like sessionID in your request headers. Are you using the cookie manager?

Comment: RaGe probably hit the nail on the head:  Cookie Manager!  When you successfully login the session is set in a cookie, which is more often than not needed for the re-direct to be successful.

Comment: Guys, Appreciate your comments. I added the cookie manager. RaGe, how can I work with the session id?